# get the value of an attribute of another element when link is clicked

Tags: jquery

Ok, new development, I have the correct values in id and tekst, but the page doesn't redirect correctly, it just refreshed, without errors. Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>my page</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light+Two" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/todo.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
<p>Hallo <a href="profile.php?user=Christophe">Christophe</a>!</p>

<nav class="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="dnperm">Notificaties toestaan</a></li>
    <li><a href="update.php">Details wijzigen</a></li>
    <li><a href="changepassword.php">Wachtwoord wijzigen</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Afmelden</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<script>
var dnperm = document.getElementById('dnperm');

dnperm.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if(!window.Notification) {
      alert('Sorry, notificaties worden niet ondersteund.');
  } else {
      Notification.requestPermission(function(p) {
          console.log(p);
      });
  }
  });
</script>   

<script src="includes/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/f_clone_Notify.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
var tekst;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id;

$('input[id="id"]').change( function(e) {
if($(this).is(':checked')){
  window.location = "mark.php?as=done&item=" + $(this).val();
}
else
  {
    window.location = "mark.php?as=notdone&item=" + $(this).val();
  }

});

$('.item').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
    tekst = $(this).text();
});
    //$('#id').attr('value');
    //id = $('#id').attr('value');

    //console.log('click');
    //url = "mark.php?as=edit&item=" + id + "&tekst=" + tekst;


    //$( '#wijzigen' ).attr("href", url);
});

function wijzigen(id) {
    url = "mark.php?as=edit&item=" + id + "&tekst=" + tekst;

    $( '#wijzigen' ).attr("href", url);
}
</script>

<div class="list">
  <h1 class="header">C1pa To Do</h1>

          <ul class="items">
              <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="id" value="1"   />
          <span id="item" contenteditable="true" class="item">edit text</span>
                            <a href="" class="hidden">
                    <script>
    var notify;

    window.setInterval(function() {
        if(Notification.permission === "default") {
            console.log("Notificaties niet toegestaan");
        } else {
            notify = new Notification("Nieuw bericht van C1pa To Do", {
                body: "edit text",
                icon: "images/notification.ico",
                tag:"1"
            });

            notify.onclick = function() {
                window.location = "mark.php?as=done&item=" + this.tag;
            }
        }
    }, 60000);
  </script>                 </a>
                <a href="" onclick="wijzigen(1)" id="wijzigen" value="1" class="done-button">wijzigen</a>
                                        <!--<a href="mark.php?as=notdone&item=" class="done-button">Niet gedaan</a>-->
                                  </li>
              <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="id" value="2"   />
          <span id="item" contenteditable="true" class="item">do something else db</span>
                            <a href="" class="hidden">
                    <script>
    var notify;

    window.setInterval(function() {
        if(Notification.permission === "default") {
            console.log("Notificaties niet toegestaan");
        } else {
            notify = new Notification("Nieuw bericht van C1pa To Do", {
                body: "do something else db",
                icon: "images/notification.ico",
                tag:"2"
            });

            notify.onclick = function() {
                window.location = "mark.php?as=done&item=" + this.tag;
            }
        }
    }, 60000);
  </script>                 </a>
                <a href="" onclick="wijzigen(2)" id="wijzigen" value="2" class="done-button">wijzigen</a>
                                        <!--<a href="mark.php?as=notdone&item=" class="done-button">Niet gedaan</a>-->
                                  </li>
              <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="id" value="11"   />
          <span id="item" contenteditable="true" class="item">something new</span>
                            <a href="" class="hidden">
                                        </a>
                <a href="" onclick="wijzigen(11)" id="wijzigen" value="11" class="done-button">wijzigen</a>
                                        <!--<a href="mark.php?as=notdone&item=" class="done-button">Niet gedaan</a>-->
                                  </li>
          </ul>

  <form class="item-add" action="add.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Hier iets typen" class="input" autocomplete="off" required>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Toevoegen">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully I put the code correct in here now so you can run it (see comments)

Comment: A few things. First, please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP. Next, are you duplicating ID's in your loop? Third, do you get any errors in your console? You question should include a [mcve] with an emphasis on *minimal*

Comment: ^^ ideally using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) so it's **runnable** on site.

Comment: Sorry about all the code.
I don't get any message in the console.
when I put a breakpoint at the specific line: <code>$("#wijzigen").click(function(){</code>, it doesn't go into the loop, it jumps over it, while it stops on the breakpoint, it doesn't go in the function. Hope that helps.
Maybe it's worth mentioning that I'm a bit new at coding.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to get the Id when you already know.

I think you are trying to get the value of Id.
If so, you can use
           id = $('#id').val();
           Instead of id = $('#id').attr('value');

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, also look at my comment above for more information.